# Error when display a version of react-native

Tags: react-native

When I check a version of react-native the error outputs like this:

```
   react-native -v
fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'
    at Object.chmodSync (fs.js:1027:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/copyToClipBoard.js:50:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/middleware/copyToClipBoardMiddleware.js:8:47)
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Neeeko Linux, ubuntu

Comment: have you tried reinstalling `npm install -g react-native-cli` to fix the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have a permission error it seems ¯_(ツ)_/¯


or 

Now clean the project...

cd android 
gradlew clean
```

Comment: Why I need clean the project? This is not working, even I wrote in none project folder

Comment: npm install    or    npm install  -g react-native-cli   or react-native upgrade or npm install react-native@letest_version